# max y min dentro de sum SQL

Tags: sql

Necesito mostrar el mes con más ventas y el mes con menos ventas, para esto tengo el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE Ventas (
id INT primary key,
idmes INT,
ventas INT);
CREATE TABLE Mes (
idmes INT primary key,
mes VARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO Ventas VALUES
(1, 7, 5), (2, 6, 5), (3, 5, 10), (4, 3, 6), (5,
7, 10),(8, 6,1), (9,3, 12),(10,9,8), (11, 12, 5), (12, 6,
0),(13, 6, 5),(14, 12, 1), (15, 8, 7), (16, 1, 3), (17, 6,
2),(19, 5,2), (20, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO Mes VALUES
('1','Enero'),('2','Marzo'),('3','Abril'),('4','Febrero'),('5','Mayo'),
('6','Julio'),('7','Septiembre'),('8','junio'),('9','Agosto')
,('10','Octubre'),('11','Noviembre'),('12','Diciembre');

select mes, SUM(ventas) as ventasT 
from (
(select mes, MAX(ventasT) from ventas  
inner join mes on mes.idmes = ventas.idmes
group by mes order by ventasT desc limit 1)
UNION
( select mes, MIN(ventasT) from ventas  
inner join mes on mes.idmes = ventas.idmes
group by mes order by ventasT asc limit 1) )
usuarios;
```

Me marco error diciendo que la sintaxis de union está equivocada desde la primera línea, espero su respuesta. 
Lo que necesito es mostrar el mes con más ventas que sería Julio con 18 y el mes con menos ventas que sería Diciembre con 6

Comment: Ya la edité, compañero

Comment: Para que base de datos?

Comment: @JoseLuisGarcia, es necesario que indiques en tu pregunta ¿con que motor de base de datos estas trabajando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

- Las columnas `ventasT` y `mes` no existen.
- Si utilizas `MAX()` solo vas a obtener el registro de `Ventas` con más `ventas`, pero **necesitas sumarlos primero para saber el total** y luego poder aplicar esta función.
- Si utilizas `MIN()` solo vas a obtener el registro de `Ventas` con menos `ventas`...

### Actualización:

Después de una informativa y constructiva conversación con @gbianchi y tras varias observaciones de su parte, convenimos en que una mejor solución a este problema podría ser la siguiente consulta:

#### Solución:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT M.mes FROM Mes AS M WHERE M.idmes = T.idmes) AS mes,
  T.ventasT
FROM (
  (SELECT
      idmes,
      SUM(ventas) AS ventasT
    FROM Ventas
    GROUP BY idmes
    ORDER BY ventasT DESC
    LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT
      idmes,
      SUM(ventas) AS ventasT
    FROM Ventas
    GROUP BY idmes
    ORDER BY ventasT ASC
    LIMIT 1)
) AS T
```

#### Descripción:

La primer consulta del `UNION` suma las `ventas` de registros de la tabla `Ventas` agrupandolos por `idmes` para luego ordenarlos por el total de forma descendiente (*mayor primero*) y solo devolver solo 1.

La segunda consulta del `UNION` es casi idéntica, solo se modifica el orden a ascendente (*menor primero*).

Al unir el resultado de ambas obtenemos el mes con mayor y menor ventas.

Finalmente en la consulta principal hacemos una sub-consulta para obtener el nombre del mes de estos 2 registros.

---

#### <s>Solución</s>

<s>Teniendo en cuenta lo mencionado anteriormente, podrías obtener el resultado esperado así:</s>

```
(SELECT
    M.mes,
    SUM(V.ventas) AS ventasT
  FROM Ventas AS V
    INNER JOIN Mes AS M
      ON M.idmes = V.idmes
  GROUP BY V.idmes
  ORDER BY ventasT DESC
  LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
    M.mes,
    SUM(V.ventas) AS ventasT
  FROM Ventas AS V
    INNER JOIN Mes AS M
      ON M.idmes = V.idmes
  GROUP BY V.idmes
  ORDER BY ventasT ASC
  LIMIT 1)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0563c/6/0)</kbd>

#### Descripción:

La primer consulta suma las `ventas` de registros de la tabla `Ventas` agrupandolos por `idmes` para luego ordenarlos por el total en orden descendiente (*mayor primero*) y solo devolver el último.

La segundo consulta es casi idéntica, solo se modifica el orden a ascendente (*menor primero*).

Comment: Cierto, además la tabla de meses es incorrecta, pues por ejemplo identifica el mes 4 como febrero, cuando debería ser abril

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100526/discussion-between-marcos-and-gbianchi).